# how to list every available identifier in ffi of pypy cffi?

Tags: python, c, pypy, python-cffi

I can list available function names and enumerator names by

```
lib = ffi.dlopen(...)
print dir(lib)
```

Howerver, dir(lib) doesn't return defined typedefs and structs.

When I tried to load an arbitrary module with an arbitrary c header file using cffi, I had to parse the header file to get the list of typedefs and structs. Is there a better way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible so far to enumerate the types.  You could file an enhancement request at https://bitbucket.org/cffi/cffi/issues.